# android not processing JSON object

Tags: php, android, json

i am trying to process json response sent by php and i am receiving through Volley response in this android code but after some debugging i figured out that the portion of code processing the json object in not executing strating from the line JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response); i printed a Log before it and it's printing , so if you please help me identify the problem i would be greatful.
android code:

```
          private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();
            try {
                Log.d("Login","You're in the try portion of the code");
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    Log.d("Login", "user successfully logged in");
                    session.setLogin(true);
                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "login");
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

php code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 

/**
* File to handle all API requests
* Accepts GET and POST
* 
* Each request will be identified by TAG
* Response will be JSON data

/**
* check for POST request 
*/
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
// get tag
$tag = $_POST['tag'];


// include db handler
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// response Array
$response = array("tag" => $tag, "error" => FALSE);

// check for tag type
if ($tag == 'login') {

    // Request type is check Login
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check for user
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
    if ($user != false) {
        // user found
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user not found
        // echo json with error = 1
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else if ($tag == 'register') {
    // Request type is Register new user
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check if user is already existed
    if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
        // user is already existed - error response
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // store user
        $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registartion";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
} else {
    // user failed to store
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Unknow 'tag' value. It should be either 'login' or 'register'";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameter 'tag' is missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

response in the logcat:

```
09-16 02:14:11.785: D/LoginActivity(4314): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0029</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>143512</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='D:\wamp\www\android_login_api\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
09-16 02:14:11.785: D/LoginActivity(4314): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0045</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>158264</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>DB_Functions->__construct(  )</td><td title='D:\wamp\www\android_login_api\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>20</td></tr>
09-16 02:14:11.785: D/LoginActivity(4314): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0060</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>162616</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>DB_Connect->connect(  )</td><td title='D:\wamp\www\android_login_api\include\DB_Functions.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\DB_Functions.php<b>:</b>13</td></tr>
09-16 02:14:11.785: D/LoginActivity(4314): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0072</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>163184</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect' target='_new'>mysql_connect</a>
09-16 02:14:11.785: D/LoginActivity(4314): (  )</td><td title='D:\wamp\www\android_login_api\include\DB_Connect.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\DB_Connect.php<b>:</b>18</td></tr>
09-16 02:14:11.785: D/LoginActivity(4314): </table></font>
09-16 02:14:11.785: D/LoginActivity(4314): {"tag":"login","error":false,"uid":"55ef78acac6190.14514751","user":{"name":"Taha Souri 5","email":"taha_sr2002@yahoo.com","created_at":"2015-09-09 02:09:16","updated_at":null}}

09-17 01:03:17.081: W/System.err(24259): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
09-17 01:03:17.081: W/System.err(24259):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
09-17 01:03:17.081: W/System.err(24259):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
09-17 01:03:17.081: W/System.err(24259):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
09-17 01:03:17.081: W/System.err(24259):    at info.androidhive.loginandregistration.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:104)
09-17 01:03:17.081: W/System.err(24259):    at info.androidhive.loginandregistration.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:97)
09-17 01:03:17.081: W/System.err(24259):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
09-17 01:03:17.081: W/System.err(24259):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
09-17 01:03:17.081: W/System.err(24259):    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
09-17 01:03:17.082: W/System.err(24259):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
09-17 01:03:17.082: W/System.err(24259):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
09-17 01:03:17.082: W/System.err(24259):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
09-17 01:03:17.082: W/System.err(24259):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5322)
09-17 01:03:17.082: W/System.err(24259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 01:03:17.082: W/System.err(24259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-17 01:03:17.082: W/System.err(24259):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
09-17 01:03:17.082: W/System.err(24259):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
09-17 01:03:17.082: W/System.err(24259):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the other php codes:

```
<?php 


class DB_Functions {

private $db;

//put your code here
// constructor
function __construct() {
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $this->db = new DB_Connect();
    $this->db->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {

}

/**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details 
        $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Get user by email and password
 */
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
    // check for result 
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $salt = $result['salt'];
        $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
        // check for password equality
        if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            // user authentication details are correct
            return $result;
        }
    } else {
        // user not found
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Check user is existed or not
 */
public function isUserExisted($email) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT email from users WHERE email = '$email'");
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        // user existed 
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not existed
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Encrypting password
 * @param password
 * returns salt and encrypted password
 */
public function hashSSHA($password) {

    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
}

/**
 * Decrypting password
 * @param salt, password
 * returns hash string
 */
public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

    $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

    return $hash;
}

}

?>

<?php  
class DB_Connect {

// constructor
function __construct() {

}

// destructor
function __destruct() {
    // $this->close();
}

// Connecting to database
public function connect() {
    require_once 'include/Config.php';
    // connecting to mysql
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
    // selecting database
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());

    // return database handler
    return $con;
}

// Closing database connection
public function close() {
    mysql_close();
}

}

?>
```

Comment: if processing json code doesn't start, the program may be terminated by other exception before processing json...

Comment: Hope, PHP Output have set Header Content-Type: application/json so that it can be readable by any JSON parser

Comment: <?php header('Content-Type: application/json'); //here your code for output ?> this will work to parse

Comment: Please post the entire crash report from the logcat you might be getting some sort of exception.

Comment: Ok, @MarmikBhatt thank you i'm missling this line in header , i will try again and report.

Comment: @calvinfly i tested it out it's only stopped by the excceptions in the portion of code where i am try to process Json

Comment: @MarmikBhatt i added that line still nothing changed, my new php code:

Comment: Hi, Need to show me your code

Comment: where you have set the header?

Comment: @MarmikBhatt in the begginging of the page after <? php , is that right?

Comment: unnecessary data output is making JSON output unreadable :)

Comment: @MarmikBhatt 
  
     
 
i edited it like this , but still the same , i think i have a lot of unnecessary output judging by the output in the logcat , but i don't know where it's coming from, i added the other php files in the question , maybe you can help me find out the source of all this output since i'm new to php.

Comment: @VaibhavBarad i posted the crash report ,have a look please, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this...

```
 $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
 header('Content-Type:application:json;');
if ($user != false) {
    // user found
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
    $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
    $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
    $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
    $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];

} else {
    // user not found
    // echo json with error = 1
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
    $response["user"] = null;
}
 echo json_encode($response);
```